WinAppDriver - Unable get the text from TextBlock but shows in Inspect tool
I am trying to get text from one of the TextBlock control in a WPF application, but it returns Text/Name property as "General Properties", but it's not the case for other similar controls in the application. I can see the text, automation id in Inspect tool,
getting element cannot be found error when I tried to access the control using automation id.
however I can access it thru parent control and I get the correct automation id but not the Name or Text property, see below image, appreciate your help, thank you

